# Python: Does the interpreter optimize statements like any([implicit for loop])?

Tags: python, optimization

I was wondering what type of optimizations are done automatically by the python interpreter.
E.g. I have the following code to check whether a string starts with any substrings in `startList`:

```
def startswithAny(string, startList):
    return any([string.startswith(x) for x in startList])
```

Let's assume `startList` contains 1000 entries, but `string.startswith(startList[0])` already yields true. What will happen? Will `[string.startswith(x) for x in startList]` still be fully evaluated? Or will the interpreter recognize that any() yields true already?

If not, than IMHO it makes more sense to write codes like these non-pythonic, like this:

```
def startswithAny(string, startList):
    for x in startList:
        if string.startswith(x): 
            return True
    return False
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `any` will honour short circuit. The problem is that as you use a list, you first compute the full list, and only then call `any` on the full list.

If you really want to use the short circuit, you should use a generator instead of a list:

```
def startswithAny(string, startList):
    return any((string.startswith(x) for x in startList))
```

(square brackets replaced with parentheses)

Demo using timeit:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('any([i.startswith("ab") for i in lst])',
                        'lst = [ "abc" + str(i) for i in range(10000)]', number=10000)
17.005268767956352
>>> timeit.timeit('any((i.startswith("ab") for i in lst))',
                        'lst = [ "abc" + str(i) for i in range(10000)]', number=10000)
0.006302962841857607
```

Comment: Oh yes, I must have missed that. Thanks for pointing it out. Can you think of any usage of any([list comprehension]) which cannot be replaced  by a generator expression? Or you think it's safe to say that this combination can always be replaced by a generator expression like in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the `any` function is **guaranteed to short circuit** that means that the moment it finds an element that's True it terminates. The `any()` code is essentially equivalent to the following:

```py
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

As you can see the moment an element is True, the loop is stopped.

So yes the code you wrote at the end is essentially equivalent to running `any()` on it. `any()` is the more pythonic way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I guess I wasn't specific enough w.r.t my question. What I meant was: Will my implicit for-loop `[string.startswith(x) for x in startList]` still be evaluated fully before it is passed to any as a fully evaluated list (yes, any() obviously will short-circuit)? Or can any() already interfere into the for loop so that it's not necessary to evaluate it completely?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. jizhilong and Serge Ballesta have good answers to that question

Answer (score 1):

According to [the document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), `any` guarantees short circuit.

But your usage will break that optimization, as a list comprehension expression will get each element evaluated, so you should pass a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) instead, which means the more optimized way is  `any(string.startswith(x) for x in startList)`